# Can you change the value of the Name property of a Type at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to change/override the Name property of a Type?

Given the class definition:

```
class Sample
{}
```

Can you change the value that `typeof(Sample).Name` returns?

I'm using an custom serialization library, which literally use `typeof(T).Name` in their source code:

```
writer.WriteStartElement(typeof(T).Name);
writer.WriteValue(item);
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: when saying name do you mean the variable's name?

Comment: @CodeCaster "because some code I can't control is using this to get this value to serialize." is the context

Comment: For info, I dug through the `.Name` implementation, and it basically terminates at an unmanaged function: `[SecurityCritical, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, DllImport("QCall", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] private static extern void ConstructName(RuntimeTypeHandle handle, TypeNameFormatFlags formatFlags, StringHandleOnStack retString)`. So if there *is* a way of spoofing this, it is completely secret and undocumented.

Comment: Can't you use an XML manipulation class to change the generated XML afterwards?

Comment: good idea; xslt would be pretty trivial to rename one element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot change the `.Name` of a `Type` at runtime. However, most serialization libraries allow you to have some control of the processing of names, either by providing a custom "binder" (etc), or by annotating the type with attributes to indicate the preferred name to use (note: most libraries that allow attributes *also* allow the name to be provided via runtime configuration of the serialization library).

An important question, then, is: what is the serialization library that is being used here?

If the serialization library doesn't support this, and cannot be changed, then the only alternative (short of renaming `Sample`) to all of this is to create a type (either by hand, or via `TypeBuilder` at runtime) that *looks* like the original type, but with a different code, and similarly: create code that translates between the two types.

Comment: what if there is already a class `TheNameIWant`? Then I can not rename `Sample`, or create a type at runtime...

Comment: @last you can, in a different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to accomplish such a task. CLR does similar thing with marshalled by ref objects, but I doubt that it will allow you to "rename" your class or its property(field) in such a way.

Your best bet is to either conform to the old code or(the better one)is to replace or change the serialization routines to be less rigid.

Answer (score 0):

As for XML serialization using the `XmlSerialization` library in the BCL, you can override the xml Element name to be generated using the following attribute:

```
[XmlElement("SomeOtherName")]
public class Sample{...}
```

Comment: that depends entirely on what serialization library is being used; the approach to use varies hugely

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I'm specifically talking about the `XmlSerialization` lib.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option for me since I'm using a custom serialization library which use 'typeof(T).Name' in their source code...

Comment: @lastr2d2 in that case, your options are: 1) live with it, 2) change the name of `class Sample` in your code, 3) add a separate DTO type that you use **just** for serialization, 4) write lots and lots of code to generate DTOs automatically with different names. I suspect I'd go with "2" or "3".

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you mentioned you want to control the name during serialize

If you want to change the name during the serialization, you can use the following attributes

```
[DataContract(Name = "NewName")] 
[XmlRoot("NewName")] 
class Sample
{
}
```

Comment: that depends *entirely* on what serialization library is being used; the approach to use varies hugely